# Python 3 script for logging into a website using the Requests module

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to write some Python (3.3.2) code to log in to a website using the Requests module. Here is the form section of the login page:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.ibvpn.com/billing/dologin.php" name="frmlogin">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="236647d2da7c8408ceb78178ba03876ea1f2b687" />

<div class="logincontainer">

    <fieldset>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="username">Email Address:</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input class="xlarge" name="username" id="username" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input class="xlarge" name="password" id="password" type="password"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div align="center">

          <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" /> Remember Me
            </p>

          <p><a href="pwreset.php">Request a Password Reset</a></p>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

</div>

<div class="actions">
<input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Login" />
</div>

</form>
```

Here is my code, trying to deal with hidden input:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ibvpn.com/billing/clientarea.php'

body = {'username':'my email address','password':'my password'}

s = requests.Session()

loginPage = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(loginPage.text)

hiddenInputs = soup.findAll(name = 'input', type = 'hidden')

for hidden in hiddenInputs:
    name = hidden['name']
    value = hidden['value']
    body[name] = value

r = s.post(url, data = body)
```

This just returns the login page. If I post my login data to the URL in the 'action' field, I get a 404 error.

I've seen other posts on StackExchange where automatic cookie handling doesn't seem to work, so I've also tried dealing with the cookies manually using:

```
cookies = dict(loginPage.cookies)

r = s.post(url, data = body, cookies = cookies)
```

But this also just returns the login page.

I don't know if this is related to the problem, but after I've run either variant of the code above, entering `r.cookies` returns `<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>`

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Would you post your finished code as an answer (if you still have it)?  I would find it helpful.

Comment: Hi @Magwich, it's as above except I added `User-Agent` to the headers: `s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36'` and posted to the 'action' URL as suggested in the answer: `s.post(soup.form['action'], data = body, headers = {'Referer':'http://www.ibvpn.com/index/'})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading the wrong URL. The form has an `action` attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.ibvpn.com/billing/dologin.php" name="frmlogin">
```

so you *must* post your login information to:

```
https://www.ibvpn.com/billing/dologin.php
```

instead of posting back to the login page. POST to `soup.form['action']` instead:

```
r = s.post(soup.form['action'], data=body)
```

Your code is handling cookies just fine; I can see that `s.cookies` holds a cookie after requesting the login form, for example.

If this still doesn't work (a 404 is returned), then the server is using additional techniques to detect scripts vs. real browsers. Usually this is done by parsing the request headers. Look at your browser headers and replicate those. It may just be the `User-Agent` header that they parse, but `Accept-*` headers and `Referrer` can also play a role.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks a lot for the quick reply. Posting to that URL returns a 404 error.

Comment: @Tom: Most likely, they are using further techniques to detect a real browser. Adjust the headers to match that of your browser (usually the user agent, but other headers may be required).

Comment: @Tom: However, posting to the `clientarea.php` URL is definitely not the right way to log in, not when the form has an explicit `action` attribute you should honour.

Comment: Hey, that's done it. Added `s.headers['Referer'] = 'http://www.ibvpn.com/index/'` (and posted to the URL specified by the action attribute) and now I get the correct page. Many thanks.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want the 'Referer' header on the Session. Session headers are for headers you want on _every_ request (e.g. User-Agent), per-request headers are for headers that apply to a single request (e.g. Referer).

Comment: @Lukasa: OK. I added the `headers = {'Referer':'http://www.ibvpn.com/index/'}` to the `s.post` command and it works like that. Thank you.